# Does Doctor Dolittle ever use animals for unusual transport?

Tags: doctor-dolittle

Doctor Dolittle can talk to animals and has no hesitation to use them for his work. Yet I don't seem to recall him ever using animals to get around for non-normal use (for example, he's always taking a car or boat, instead of flying across sea by bird. I'm not referring to riding a horse, or even a Pushmi-Pullyu).

So, am I remembering correctly? Does Doctor Dolittle use animals for unusual transport anytime during the original books by Hugh Lofting?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

He flies to the moon on the back of a giant Luna Moth named Jamaro Bumblelily.  I suppose that counts as unusual transportation....

[image]

Sources:

- [Doctor Dolittle in the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Dolittle_in_the_Moon)
- [Doctor Dolittle's Garden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Dolittle%27s_Garden)

Also, at the end of [The Voyages of Doctor Dolittle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Voyages_of_Doctor_Dolittle), he and his friends travel home under the sea inside the shell of the Great Pink Sea Snail.

> Our new quarters we found very satisfactory. Inside the spacious
>   shell, the snail’s wide back was extremely comfortable to sit and
>   lounge on—better than a sofa, when you once got accustomed to the damp
>   and clammy feeling of it. He asked us, shortly after we started, if we
>   wouldn’t mind taking off our boots, as the hobnails in them hurt his
>   back as we ran excitedly from one side to another to see the different
>   sights.

-p. 307 of the June 1988 Dell paperback edition (which does not include the following color image, but it is in the [Project Gutenberg copy](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/1154/1154-h/1154-h.htm#Page_340))

[image]

Comment: Great. But anything in-earth?

Comment: Yes, added it to the answer.

Answer (score 12):

## The Monkey Bridge

Dr. Dolittle uses a whole bunch of monkeys as a bridge, to get across a chasm to the Land of the Monkeys.

> But the big monkey who was carrying the pig dropped him on the ground and cried out to the other monkeys.
> "Boys—a bridge! Quick!—Make a bridge! We've only a minute to do it. They've got the Captain loose, and he's coming on like a deer. Get lively! A bridge! A bridge!"
> The Doctor began to wonder what they were going to make a bridge out of, and he gazed around to see if they had any boards hidden any place.
> But when he looked back at the cliff, there, hanging across the river, was a bridge all ready for him—made of living monkeys! For while his back was turned, the monkeys—quick as a flash—had made themselves into a bridge, just by holding hands and feet.
> And the big one shouted to the Doctor, "Walk over! Walk over—all of you—hurry!"
> Gub–Gub was a bit scared, walking on such a narrow bridge at that dizzy height above the river. But he got over all right; and so did all of them.
> John Dolittle was the last to cross. And just as he was getting to the other side, the King's men came rushing up to the edge of the cliff.
> <sub>[*The Story of Dr. Dolittle*, chapter 7: "The Bridge of Apes"](http://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/221/the-story-of-doctor-dolittle/5621/chapter-7-the-bridge-of-apes/)</sub>

Comment: Good find, but I meant mainly cross-sea long-distance transport (ie riding in a whale, bird flying him etc.)